# Packard Bell TS11HR touchpad scroll gesture doesn't work

Tags: touchpad, 14.04, scrolling

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my PackardBell TS11HR.
Scrolling by dragging right side bar on touchpad doesn't work while two-finger dragging does work.
Is anything wrong with touchpad drivers?
Is there any thing I can do? It works on Windows 7 & 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Mouse and touchpad" settings menu there is a "Two finger scroll" option that is now enabled by default. Disabling it shall turn the scrolling behavior back to right side.

Comment: thanks buddy. that works. but is there any way I can use them both. there are cases I need to use two-finger-scroll.